# Convert data from months, days, hours, minutes, into just minutes?

Tags: python, date

I have a .csv file of data in Months/Days/Hours/Minutes, and I need to convert it into just minutes. I can convert days and hours fine, but I am struggling with how to convert the months into minutes as they are not a standard length.

This is a snapshot of my data, the full file is too large to post here.

[image]

This is my code so far. It reads the file and computes the time in minutes correctly from the Day, Hour, and Minute columns. I can't think how to make it accurately calculate the number of minutes in each month - my rough idea was to define how many days in a month, then read which month it is from the data and use this as an index to cross-reference this with the month lengths variable and multiply that by 1440 (number of minutes in a day). But I don't know how to make Python do this?

```
# Import packages
import pandas as pd

# Open  data file
data_file_name = "data_file.csv"
data_file = pd.read_csv(data_file_name, header=2)

# Extract DHI solar data
solar_data = data_file["DHI"]

# Extract time points
# Define number of days in each month
month_lengths = [0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31] # Always one month out of sync

time_data = ((data_file["Day"]-1)*1440) + (data_file["Hour"]*60) + data_file["Minute"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has full calendar support in the [`datetime` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).  Use it.

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime(data_file["Year"], data_file["Month"], data_file["Day"], data_file["Hour"] data_file["Minute"])
delta = dt - datetime.datetime(data_file["Year"], 1, 1)
time_data = delta.total_seconds() // 60
```

This has the advantage of automatically adjusting for leap years too.

Comment: This gives me the error: raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'> ? Do I need to convert my data to another format first?

Comment: @UnaDavies I guess so.  I thought since you were already doing math on them they were integers to begin with.